# I need to implement start and stop worker queues functionality in bullmq

Tags: node.js, redis, bullmq

I need to implement one functionality to start and stop worker queue using bullmq.

The complete scenario is when someone presses the start button on the front-end side. the job will be added to the worker and the queue will start and processing it. in the middle of the worker implementation if one will press the stop button. it needs to get a stop or can say pause the queue job. and then if one will start the job again. it should start again with the same queue job.

I would really appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to do `worker.pause()`?

Comment: I thought that will only pause the worker for the next job not for the current one. am I right?